# .NET FormView using ItemInserted and ItemInserting EventHandlers is Not Saving To Database

Tags: c#, .net, formview

It's a simple stored procedure taking a few string parameters. I can call it independently, and it works as expected. The FormView hits the ItemInserting and ItemInserted event handlers as expected. But the stored procedure is not called.

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="sdsResourceEdit" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>"
    InsertCommand="CLIENT_DASHBOARD_RESOURCE_INSERT" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:FormParameter Name="caption" FormField="Caption" Type="String" />
        <asp:FormParameter Name="url" FormField="URL" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The code behind ItemInserting handles a file upload, and then sets values.

```
        e.Values["fileName"] = FileName;
        e.Values["filePath"] = FilePath;
```

Do I have to manually call the "ItemInsert" action (somehow) because I assigned this custom EventHandler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was actually a mistake elsewhere in my FormView. I was using

```
<asp:Button>
```

which works fine on FormView *if* you are not using any FileUpload controls. As soon as I added the FileUpload control, the FormView began to misbehave. To fix this, use

```
<asp:LinkButton>
```

instead.